# PWA Studio server configuration

Tags: server-setup, pwa, pwa-studio

We using PWA Studio 2.1.0 and have an issue with the server configuration and the proxy settings

The url of the website is http://pwa.agen.to/

But PWA studio is run at http://0.0.0.0:10000/

So the browser is auto directing

Is there a config doc or a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue and figured out that the URL given in .env was not a secure one.

Please check if you are giving URL containing "https://" and not "http://" in .env.

check:

"MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL" : "should contain an https:// one"
MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_PROVIDE_SECURE_HOST=1
MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_ADD_UNIQUE_HASH=1

Hope it may work.

Answer (score 0):

We used this setup

https://github.com/rossmc/how-to-venia

We had it set to developer and when we set to staging it works!

run the staging environment which will more closely reflect production

```
yarn build:prod
yarn start
```